# OSM roads polygonized in PostGIS = nonsense

Tags: postgis, polygonize

I have a dump of OSM data in my city and wrote a query to polygonize it. In the first attempt, the result looked like this:

[image]

The problem was that OSM lines were not split and I guessed that the polygonizer only made polygons of entire linestrings:

[image]

^^ here, the green nodes are used for polygons, the blue ones are ignored, together with line 3.

Since `st_split` supports slice by multiple points only in PostGIS 2.2, I decided to write [a Python script](http://pastebin.com/ttYXBUmJ) to do this. Together with some SQL code, it splits lines into segments that respect intersections. Every road joining an intersection is unique.

The way I understand it now:

[image]

[The SQL code](http://pastebin.com/4SVNT8FE):

```
CREATE VIEW nodes AS
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () id, st_node(way) nd
FROM rd_sliced_roads;


DROP VIEW IF EXISTS pg;
CREATE VIEW pg AS
WITH   
    polygroup AS (SELECT ST_Polygonize(way) initial FROM nodes),
    dumped AS (SELECT (st_dump(initial)).geom result FROM polygroup)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () id, result
FROM dumped;
```

The result is still quite similar: polygons are ignored, even though lines join each other. Red lines are both source and st_nodified lines. Why does `st_polygonize` ignore these small quarters?

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

Turned out, doing `st_union` instead of `st_node` did the trick. I still wonder what `st_polygonize` is so sensitive to?

[image]

So, the algorythm to make polygons is very simple:

```
with united as (select st_union(way) w from planet_osm_lines /* filter highways here */),
     polied as (select st_polygonize(w) w from united)
select (st_dump(w)).geom poly from polied;
```

Comment: Duplicated segments can throw it off; these would be removed by `ST_Union`.

Comment: @dbaston I'll check that, but don't think that was the case.